How to extend login.blade.php in laravel
I have my login.blade.php which is a part of laravel breeze. This is login.blade.php:
@section('login')
<x-guest-layout>
...other code
</x-guest-layout>
@endsection

In my welcome.blade.php, I am trying to yield the login section:
@extends('auth.login')
<!Doctype HTML>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Laravel</title>
</head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('css/welcome.css') }}">

<body class="background">
    <div class="login-container">
        @yield('login')
    </div>
</body>

</html>

However nothing is appearing in the UI.
Where am I going wrong?

Forget @extends layout pattern.
The mainstream in current Laravel is the Blade component layout.
https://laravel.com/docs/11.x/blade#building-layouts
Create a Blade component with only a login form.
// resources/views/components/login-form.blade.php

<div>
    <form method="POST" action="{{ route('login') }}">
        @csrf
    </form>
</div>

Components can be used anywhere within Blade.
// welcome.blade.php

<body class="background">
    <div class="login-container">
        <x-login-form />
    </div>
</body>

